# Reference error: "__decorate is not defined" when passing input to an angular directive

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-directives

I am currently trying to pass an object to my created directive below and the element property remains undefined even though the alias is matching the @input decorator. The onClick method is being hit correctly as well.

```
  import { Directive, Input, HostListener } from '@angular/core';

  @Directive({
      selector: '[nextFocus]' 
  })

  export class NextFocusDirective {
  @Input('nextFocus')
  element: any;

  @HostListener('click', ['$event'])
   public onClick($event: Event) {
      debugger;
      $($event.target).focus();
   }
 }
```

Here it where it is being used in the html:

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-success"
    ngbTooltip="Add"
    [nextFocus]="nextElement">
    <i class="mdi mdi-plus"></i>
</button>
```

I have tried various syntaxes according to the angular docs and was unable to solve it. What am I missing that causes the element property to get correctly initialized?

Comment: What are your @angular/* and typescript versions? The error msg sounds like some might need updating.

Comment: Strange, the only thing I miss is the constructor, have you tried to put the constructor and try again?

Comment: what is "nextElement"? is that a template variable? and why are you using jquery?

Comment: @funkizer running angular@5.2.3 and typescript@2.8. What makes you think updating issues?

Comment: @kalamarico I have tried adding a constuctor and it did not solve the issue. I also attempted to add the element property as an injectable into the constructor (just a naive attempt admittedly) and it didnt help. I am thinking it has something to do with how my Input is being set

Comment: Try to remove funcionality, set the minium version, remove the onclick, and set element as a different type of any, string for example, I don't know, try to do first a simple directive maybe you are right and angular dislike how it looks now

Comment: @bryan60 "nextElement" will be a native element that I want the focus to go to after the click event occurs. jquery is being used to cause the autofocus, but am open to ideas on how to do this better. Even without jquery, the element input property does not get set correctly. I tried making the element a string and was unable to have that get initialized correctly.

Comment: Did you tried to execute the linter? 'ng lint' maybe it give you any warning or something

Comment: well HTMLElements in angular have a nativeElement.focus() method already if they are focusable, so jquery is super unneeded.  however, passing elements into directives, I'm not sure if that's allowed or would work.  I'd like to see the code you used when attempting to pas a string and with the jquery / focus methods removed.

Comment: I've had weird problems with TS >2.6.2. Long shot but try npm install typescript@2.6.2

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this by adding a setter to my input property

```
private _element:any;

@Input('nextFocus')
set element(value: any) {
    this._element = value;
}
```

I could successfully utilize the element after adding it. I am thinking it has to do with the ts generation between the 2 versions causing the initial issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can also access the input property value in the ngAfterContentInit lifecycle method:

```
  export class NextFocusDirective implements AfterContentInit {

      @Input('nextFocus')
      element: any;

      @HostListener('click', ['$event'])
      public onClick($event: Event) {
         debugger;
         $($event.target).focus();
      }

      ngAfterContentInit(): void {
          const val = this.element; 
          debugger; // val will contain input property value
      }

 }
```